# How to get the directory of a package?

Tags: packages, files-and-directories

I have a package that I have placed in the `$BaseDirectory\Applications` directory so that `Needs` can find it.  I have a logo in the directory that I will return when a function is called.  However, when I call `NotebookDirectory` in the package I get the directory of the notebook (this seems like expected behavior).  I've not been able to find a corresponding *PackageDirectory* function.

How do I get the directory of a package so I can load a resource (in this case a .jpg logo) to return to the calling notebook?

**Update to show package and `$InputFileName` returns empty string**

**Update to show proper use of `$InputFileName` in package**

The package saved as an .m file in `$BaseDirectory`\Applications is:

```
BeginPackage["MyTest`"];
packageDirectory::usage="Gets the directory of the this package.";
packageLogo::usage="Gets the logo of this package.";
testfoo::usage="does this work"
Begin["`Private`"];
(* $Input only has a value as the package is being loaded so capture that
        value with `Set` in order to use it with `SetDelayed` later. *)
thisIsThePackageDirectory=$InputFileName//DirectoryName;
packageDirectory[]:=thisIsThePackageDirectory
packageLogo[]:=Import[FileNameJoin[{thisIsThePackageDirectory,"logo.jpg"}],"JPEG"] 
testfoo[]:="some text"
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

The logo.jpg file is in the same directory as the .m package.

The notebook commands are as follows.

```
Needs["MyTest`"]
Names["MyTest`*"]
(* {"packageDirectory", "packageLogo", "testfoo"} *)
packageLogo[]
(* Logo image returned *)
packageDirectory[] // InputForm
(* "C:\\ProgramData\\Mathematica\\Applications\\MyTest.m" *)
testfoo[]
(* some text *)
```

Many thanks to @Szabolcs and @Ymareth.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`FindFile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindFile.html) will tell you which file will be loaded when you ask for a particular package with the backtick syntax.

[`DirectoryName`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DirectoryName.html) will return the directory that contains a file.

Example:

```
In[1]:= FindFile["Combinatorica`"]

Out[1]= "/Applications/Mathematica 10.1.app/Contents/AddOns/Packages/Combinatorica/Kernel/init.m"
```

---

**Update:**  This solution is probably better: in your package file, use `$InputFileName` to determine the location of the package file and save it into a variable that is private to the package.  The use this variable with the function that shows the logo.

Comment: `$InputFileName` returns an empty string.

Comment: I also think `FindFile` is a bit expensive to use.  The system already knows where the package file is.  It has loaded it after all.  Why do another scan of the `$Path` directory hierarchies to "find" it and the strip the file name from it.

Comment: $InputFileName only has a value while the kernel is loading a package.  So the package itself can do something with that filename while its being loaded.

Comment: @Ymareth Ah!  It is the difference between `Set` and `SetDelayed` in my package definitions. I understand now. I had to capture the value of `$InputFileName//DirectoryName` into a variable using `Set`. This executes when the package loads.  Then I can use this variable anywhere in the `SetDelayed` defintions.  However, I was using `$InputFileName` in the `SetDelayed` definitions and these don't run until alter the package as been loaded.  Therefore, I was getting the empty string.

Comment: @Edmund That is what I meant by "use `$InputFileName` to determine the location of the package file and save it into a variable that is private to the package".

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, I see that now. I was not reading that in the correct context.  Thanks for this answer and returning to comment.