# How to follow symbolic links on disk?

Tags: packages, files-and-directories

In [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79510/how-to-get-the-directory-of-a-package) we learn that we can use `FindFile`  to get the disk location of a package.  However, I have some packages that are installed into my `$USER/Library/Mathematica/Applications/$` directory by symbolic link.

I'd like to be able to resolve the "true" path of these packages, much like the GNU `readlink` utility does.  Does Mathematica have such a function built in?  If not, by what other [preferably cross-platform] methods can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`AbsoluteFileName`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteFileName.html) will resolve symbolic links.

Example on my machine:

```
AbsoluteFileName["/Library/TeX/texbin"]
(* "/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-darwin" *)
```

Answer (score 7):

After a bit more fiddling around I found `FileInformation`, an undocumented function which takes a file name as an argument.

`FileInformation[FindFile["myPackage`"]]` returns

```
{AbsoluteFileName->/absolute/path/to/myPackage.wl,
 BlockCount->24,
 BlockSize->4096,
 ByteCount->8474,
 CreationDate->Thu 17 Oct 2019 11:06:04GMT-4.,
 Device->16777220,
 DirectoryName->$HOME/Library/Mathematica/Applications,
 FileAttributes->Missing[NotAvailable],
 FileBaseName->myPackage,FileExtension->wl,
 FileName->$HOME/Library/Mathematica/Applications/myPackage.wl,
 FileType->File,
 GID->20,
 GroupName->Missing[NotAvailable],
 Inode->28731823,
 LastAccessDate->Wed 23 Oct 2019 18:16:13GMT-4.,
 LastModificationDate->Wed 23 Oct 2019 18:16:10GMT-4.,
 LinkCount->1,
 OwnerName->Missing[NotAvailable],
 RawByteCount->12288,
 SetGroupID->False,
 SetUserID->False,
 Sticky->False,
 UID->501,
 UnixPermissionsCode->0660,
 UnixPermissionsString->-rw-rw----}
```

where I replaced my home directory with `$HOME` and the true `readlink` path with `/absolute/path/to/myPackage.wl` for privacy.  `CreationDate`, `LastAccessDate`, and `LastModificationDate` are `DateObject`s, all the left-hand sides of the rules are `"strings"`, and the right-hand sides are integers, strings, etc.

SO, what I was looking for was `"AbsoluteFileName"/.FileInformation[FindFile["myPackage`"]]`