# Creating a function, saving it in a file, and calling it in another file

Tags: function-construction, files-and-directories, external-calls

I'd like to know how to wrap up a function in a file an then how to call it in another file. For example, I've the following long piece of code which is used to create the function PlotExplorer. I prefer to avoid to copy and paste this code in each file in which I need the function PlotExplorer. Is there a way to isolate the function in a file and then call it in another file?

```
GetPlotRange::usage = 
  "GetPlotRange[gr] returns the actual unpadded plot range of \
graphics gr. GetPlotRange[gr, True] returns the actual padded plot \
range of gr. GetPlotRange can handle Graphics, Graphics3D and Graph \
objects.";
GetPlotRange[_[
   gr : (_Graphics | _Graphics3D | _Graph | _GeoGraphics), ___], 
  pad_] := GetPlotRange[gr, 
  pad];(*Handle Legended[\[Ellipsis]] and similar.*)
GetPlotRange[gr_GeoGraphics, 
  False] := (PlotRange /. 
   Quiet@AbsoluteOptions@gr);(*TODO:does not handle PlotRangePadding.*)
GetPlotRange[gr_Graph, pad_: False] := 
 Charting`get2DPlotRange[gr, pad];
GetPlotRange[gr : (_Graphics | _Graphics3D), pad_: False] := 
  Module[{r = PlotRange /. Options@gr}, 
   If[MatrixQ[r, NumericQ],(*TODO:does not handle PlotRangePadding*)r,
     Last@Last@
      Reap@Rasterize[
        Show[gr, If[pad === False, PlotRangePadding -> None, {}], 
         Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
         Ticks -> ((Sow@{##}; Automatic) &), 
         DisplayFunction -> Identity, ImageSize -> 0], 
        ImageResolution -> 1]]];


(*Joins and filters options,keeping the righmost if there are \
multiple instances of the same option.*)
filter[opts_List, head_] := 
  Reverse@DeleteDuplicatesBy[
    Reverse@FilterRules[Flatten@opts, First /@ Options@head], First];


(*Find and use SETools of Szabolcs& Halirutan*)
$SEToolsExist = 
  FileExistsQ@
   FileNameJoin@{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", "SETools", 
     "Java", "SETools.jar"};

(*If SETools exist,initiate JLink and include some functions*)
If[$SEToolsExist, Needs@"JLink`";
  JLink`InstallJava[];
  copyToClipboard[text_] := 
   Module[{nb}, nb = NotebookCreate[Visible -> False];
    NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[text, "Input"]];
    SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
    FrontEndTokenExecute[nb, "Copy"];
    NotebookClose@nb;];
  uploadButtonAction[img_] := 
   uploadButtonAction[img, "![Mathematica graphics](", ")"];
  uploadButtonAction[img_, wrapStart_String, wrapEnd_String] := 
   Module[{url}, Check[url = stackImage@img, Return[]];
    copyToClipboard@(wrapStart <> url <> wrapEnd);];
  stackImage::httperr = "Server returned respose code: `1`";
  stackImage::err = "Server returner error: `1`";
  stackImage::parseErr = "Could not parse the answer of the server.";
  stackImage[g_] := 
   Module[{url, client, method, data, partSource, part, entity, code, 
     response, error, result, parseXMLOutput}, 
    parseXMLOutput[str_String] := 
     Block[{xml = ImportString[str, {"HTML", "XMLObject"}], result}, 
      result = 
       Cases[xml, XMLElement["script", _, res_] :> StringTrim[res], 
         Infinity] /. {{s_String}} :> s;
      If[result =!= {} && StringMatchQ[result, "window.parent" ~~ __],
        Flatten@
        StringCases[result, 
         "window.parent." ~~ func__ ~~ "(" ~~ arg__ ~~ 
           ");" :> {StringMatchQ[func, "closeDialog"], 
           StringTrim[arg, "\""]}], $Failed]];
    parseXMLOutput[___] := $Failed;
    data = ExportString[g, "PNG"];
    JLink`JavaBlock[
     JLink`LoadJavaClass["de.halirutan.se.tools.SEUploader", 
      StaticsVisible -> True];
     response = 
      Check[SEUploader`sendImage@ToCharacterCode@data, 
       Return@$Failed]];
    If[response === $Failed, Return@$Failed];
    result = parseXMLOutput@response;
    If[result =!= $Failed, 
     If[TrueQ@First@result, Last@result, 
      Message[stackImage::err, Last@result]; $Failed], 
     Message[stackImage::parseErr]; $Failed]];];


GraphicsButton::usage = 
  "GraphicsButton[lbl, gr] represent a button that is labeled with \
lbl and offers functionality for the static graphics object gr. \
GraphicsButton[gr] uses a tiny version of gr as label.";
MenuItems::usage = 
  "MenuItems is an option for GraphicsButton that specifies \
additional label \[RuleDelayed] command pairs as a list to be \
included at the top of the action menu of GraphicsButton.";
Options[GraphicsButton] = 
  DeleteDuplicatesBy[
   Flatten@{MenuItems -> {}, RasterSize -> Automatic, 
     ColorSpace -> Automatic, ImageResolution -> 300, 
     Options@ActionMenu}, First];
GraphicsButton[expr_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  GraphicsButton[
   Pane[expr, ImageSize -> Small, ImageSizeAction -> "ShrinkToFit"], 
   expr, opts];
GraphicsButton[lbl_, expr_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{head, save, items = OptionValue@MenuItems, rasterizeOpts, 
    dir = $UserDocumentsDirectory, file = ""}, 
   rasterizeOpts = 
    filter[{Options@GraphicsButton, opts}, Options@Rasterize];
   save[format_] := (file = 
      SystemDialogInput["FileSave", 
       FileNameJoin@{dir, "." <> ToLowerCase@format}];
     If[file =!= $Failed && file =!= $Canceled, 
      dir = DirectoryName@file;
      Quiet@
       Export[file, 
        If[format === "NB", expr, 
         Rasterize[expr, "Image", rasterizeOpts]], format]]);
   head = Head@Unevaluated@expr;
   ActionMenu[lbl, 
    Flatten@{If[items =!= {}, items, Nothing], 
      "Copy expression" :> CopyToClipboard@expr, 
      "Copy image" :> CopyToClipboard@Rasterize@expr, 
      "Copy high-res image" :> 
       CopyToClipboard@Rasterize[expr, "Image", rasterizeOpts], 
      "Paste expression" :> Paste@expr, 
      "Paste image" :> Paste@Rasterize@expr, 
      "Paste high-res image" :> 
       Paste@Rasterize[expr, "Image", rasterizeOpts], Delimiter, 
      "Save as notebook\[Ellipsis]" :> save@"NB", 
      "Save as JPEG\[Ellipsis]" :> save@"JPEG", 
      "Save as TIFF\[Ellipsis]" :> save@"TIFF", 
      "Save as BMP\[Ellipsis]" :> save@"BMP", Delimiter, 
      Style["Upload image to StackExchange", 
        If[$SEToolsExist, Black, Gray]] :> 
       If[$SEToolsExist, uploadButtonAction@Rasterize@expr], 
      "Open image in external application" :> 
       Module[{f = 
          Export[FileNameJoin@{$TemporaryDirectory, "temp_img.tiff"}, 
           Rasterize@expr, "TIFF"]}, 
        If[StringQ@f && FileExistsQ@f, SystemOpen@f]]}, 
    filter[{Options@GraphicsButton, opts, {Method -> "Queued"}}, 
     Options@ActionMenu]]];


PlotExplorer::usage = 
  "PlotExplorer[plot] returns a manipulable version of plot. \
PlotExplorer can handle Graph and Graphics objects and plotting \
functions like Plot, LogPlot, ListPlot, DensityPlot, Streamplot, etc. \
PlotExplorer allows the modification of the plot range, image size \
and aspect ratio. If the supplied argument is a full specification of \
a plotting function holding its first argument (e.g. Plot) the result \
offers functionality to replot the function to the modified plot \
range. PlotExplorer has attribute HoldFirst.";
AppearanceFunction::usage = 
  "AppearanceFunction is an option for PlotExplorer that specifies \
the appearance function of the menu button. Use Automatic for the \
default appearance, Identity to display a classic button or None to \
omit the menu button.";
MenuPosition::usage = 
  "MenuPosition is an option for PlotExplorer that specifies the \
position of the (upper right corner of the) menu button within the \
graphics object.";
Attributes[PlotExplorer] = {HoldFirst};
Options[PlotExplorer] = {AppearanceFunction -> (Mouseover[
         Invisible@#, #] &@
       Framed[#, Background -> GrayLevel[.5, .5], RoundingRadius -> 5,
         FrameStyle -> None, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
        BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}] &), 
   MenuPosition -> Scaled@{1, 1}};
PlotExplorer[expr_, rangeArg_: Automatic, sizeArg_: Automatic, 
   ratioArg_: Automatic, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{plot = expr, held = Hold@expr, head, holdQ = True, 
    legQ = False, appearance, 
    position, $1Dplots = 
     Plot | LogPlot | LogLinearPlot | LogLogPlot, $2Dplots = 
     DensityPlot | ContourPlot | RegionPlot | StreamPlot | 
      StreamDensityPlot | VectorPlot | VectorDensityPlot | 
      LineIntegralConvolutionPlot | GeoGraphics}, head = held[[1, 0]];
   If[head === Symbol, holdQ = False; head = Head@expr];
   If[head === Legended, legQ = True;
    If[holdQ, held = held /. Legended[x_, ___] :> x;
     head = held[[1, 0]], head = Head@First@expr]];
   holdQ = holdQ && MatchQ[head, $1Dplots | $2Dplots];
   If[! holdQ, legQ = Head@expr === Legended;
    head = If[legQ, Head@First@expr, Head@expr]];
   If[Not@MatchQ[head, $1Dplots | $2Dplots | Graphics | Graph], expr, 
    DynamicModule[{dyn, gr, leg, replot, rescale, new, mid, len, 
      min = 0.1, f = {1, 1}, set, d, epilog, over = False, defRange, 
      range, size, ratio, pt1, pt1sc = None, pt2 = None, pt2sc = None,
       rect, button}, {gr, leg} = If[legQ, List @@ plot, {plot, None}];
     size = 
      If[sizeArg === Automatic, Rasterize[gr, "RasterSize"], 
       Setting@sizeArg];
     defRange = 
      If[rangeArg === Automatic, GetPlotRange[gr, False], 
       Setting@rangeArg];
     ratio = 
      If[ratioArg === Automatic, Divide @@ Reverse@size, 
       Setting@ratioArg];
     epilog = Epilog /. Quiet@AbsoluteOptions@plot;
     gr = plot;
     (*When r1 or r2 is e.g.{1,1} (scale region has zero width),
     EuclideanDistance by defult returns Infinity which is fine.*)
     d[p1_, p2_, {r1_, r2_}] := 
      Quiet@N@EuclideanDistance[Rescale[p1, r1], Rescale[p2, r2]];
     set[r_] := (range = new = r; mid = Mean /@ range;
       len = Abs[Subtract @@@ range]; pt1 = None; rect = {};);
     set@defRange;
     (*Replace plot range or insert if nonexistent*)
     replot[h_, hold_, r_] := 
      Module[{temp}, 
       ReleaseHold@
        Switch[h, $1Dplots, 
         temp = ReplacePart[
           hold, {{1, 2, 2} -> r[[1, 1]], {1, 2, 3} -> r[[1, 2]]}];
         If[MemberQ[temp, PlotRange, Infinity], 
          temp /. {_[PlotRange, _] -> (PlotRange -> r)}, 
          Insert[temp, PlotRange -> r, {1, -1}]], $2Dplots, 
         temp = ReplacePart[
           hold, {{1, 2, 2} -> r[[1, 1]], {1, 2, 3} -> 
             r[[1, 2]], {1, 3, 2} -> r[[2, 1]], {1, 3, 3} -> 
             r[[2, 2]]}];
         If[MemberQ[temp, PlotRange, Infinity], 
          temp /. {_[PlotRange, _] -> (PlotRange -> r)}, 
          Insert[temp, PlotRange -> r, {1, -1}]], _, hold]];
     rescale[h_, hold_, sc_] := 
      ReleaseHold@
       Switch[h, $1Dplots | $2Dplots, 
        If[MemberQ[hold, ScalingFunctions, Infinity], 
         hold /. {_[ScalingFunctions, _] -> (ScalingFunctions -> sc)},
          Insert[hold, ScalingFunctions -> sc, {1, -1}]], _, hold];
     appearance = 
      OptionValue@
        AppearanceFunction /. {Automatic :> (AppearanceFunction /. 
           Options@PlotExplorer)};
     position = OptionValue@MenuPosition /. Automatic -> Scaled@{1, 1};
     (*Print@Column@{rangeArg,sizeArg,ratioArg,appearance,position};*)
     button = 
      If[appearance === None, {}, 
       Inset[appearance@
         Dynamic@GraphicsButton["Menu", dyn, 
           Appearance -> If[appearance === Identity, Automatic, None],
            MenuItems -> 
            Flatten@{{Row@{"Copy PlotRange \[Rule] ", 
                  TextForm /@ range} :> (CopyToClipboard[
                  PlotRange -> range]), 
               Row@{"Copy ImageSize \[Rule] ", 
                  InputForm@size} :> (CopyToClipboard[
                  ImageSize -> size]), 
               Row@{"Copy AspectRatio \[Rule] ", 
                  InputForm@ratio} :> (CopyToClipboard[
                  AspectRatio -> ratio])}, 
              If[MatchQ[head, $1Dplots | $2Dplots], {Delimiter, 
                
                "Replot at current PlotRange" :> (gr = 
                    replot[head, held, range];), 
                "Linear" :> {gr = 
                    rescale[head, held, {Identity, Identity}];}, 
                "Log" :> {gr = 
                   rescale[head, held, {Identity, "Log"}]}, 
                "LogLinear" :> {gr = 
                   rescale[head, held, {"Log", Identity}]}, 
                "LogLog" :> {gr = 
                   rescale[head, held, {"Log", "Log"}]}}, {}], 
              Delimiter}], position, Scaled@{1, 1}, 
        Background -> None]];
     Deploy@
      Pane[EventHandler[
        Dynamic[MouseAppearance[
          Show[(*`dyn` is kept as the original expression with only \
updating `range`,`size` and `ratio`.*)
           dyn = Show[gr, PlotRange -> Dynamic@range, 
             ImageSize -> Dynamic@size, AspectRatio -> Dynamic@ratio],
            Epilog -> {epilog, 
             button, {FaceForm@{Blue, Opacity@.1}, 
              EdgeForm@{Thin, Dotted, Opacity@.5}, 
              Dynamic@rect}, {Dynamic@
               If[over && CurrentValue@"AltKey" && 
                 pt2 =!= None, {Antialiasing -> False, 
                 AbsoluteThickness@.25, GrayLevel[.5, .5], Dashing@{},
                  InfiniteLine@{pt2, pt2 + {1, 0}}, 
                 InfiniteLine@{pt2, pt2 + {0, 1}}}, {}]}}], 
          Which[over && CurrentValue@"AltKey" && pt2 =!= None, 
           Graphics@{Text[pt2, pt2, -{1.1, 1}, 
              Background -> GrayLevel[1, .7]]}, 
           CurrentValue@"ShiftKey", "LinkHand", 
           CurrentValue@"ControlKey", "ZoomView", True, Automatic]], 
         TrackedSymbols :> {gr}], {"MouseEntered" :> (over = True), 
         "MouseExited" :> (over = False), 
         "MouseMoved" :> (pt2 = MousePosition@"Graphics";), 
         "MouseClicked" :> (If[CurrentValue@"MouseClickCount" == 2, 
             set@defRange];), 
         "MouseDown" :> (pt1 = MousePosition@"Graphics";
           pt1sc = MousePosition@"GraphicsScaled";), 
         "MouseUp" :> (If[
            CurrentValue@"ControlKey" && d[pt1, pt2, new] > min, 
            range = Transpose@Sort@{pt1, pt2};]; set@range;), 
         "MouseDragged" :> (pt2 = MousePosition@"Graphics";
           pt2sc = MousePosition@"GraphicsScaled";
           
           Which[CurrentValue@"ShiftKey", 
            pt2 = MapThread[
               Rescale, {MousePosition@
                 "GraphicsScaled", {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, new}] - pt1;
            range = new - pt2;,(*Panning*)CurrentValue@"ControlKey", 
            rect = If[pt1 === None || pt2 === None, {}, 
               Rectangle[pt1, pt2]];,(*Zooming rectangle*)True, 
            f = 10^(pt1sc - pt2sc);
            
            range = (mid + (1 - f) (pt1 - mid)) + 
              f/2 {-len, len}\[Transpose](*Zofom on `pt1`*)])}, 
        PassEventsDown -> True, PassEventsUp -> True], 
       Dynamic[size, (size = #;
          
          If[CurrentValue@"ControlKey", 
           ratio = Divide @@ Reverse@#]) &], 
       AppearanceElements -> "ResizeArea", ImageMargins -> 0, 
       FrameMargins -> 0]]]];
```

Comment: just save it to a file say `plotExplorer.m` and any place it is needed, just do `<<"plotExplorer.m` or `Get[]`  on the file. Now the file is loaded. So you can just call any function in it. It is better to save all your `.m` files to known location so easy to find. See [how-to-get-the-directory-of-a-package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79510/how-to-get-the-directory-of-a-package) And it is not a good idea to make your functions start with UpperCase as these are used by Mathematica. ps. there are lots of information about making packages in Mathematica...

Comment: ... here is one from community [Building Packages: A basic tutorial](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/214901)  and many more on this forum

Comment: Hello @Nasser thank you for your suggestions. I'm trying to use Get["path\PlotExplorer.m"], but it fails. I got the error Get: Cannot open...

Comment: Try "\\" instead of one "\" (I assume you are on windows).   `Get["path\\PlotExplorer.m"]`  If the path is correct, it should really work. is it relative or absolute path? Try absolute path.

Comment: @Nasser yes I'm on windows and I'm using an absolute path. I tried also with "\\", but the error is the same (I copied the path from the top of the folder): Get["C:\Users\Gennaro\Desktop\Funzione PlotExplorer (non integrata) \
per ingrandire (zoomare,fare zoom) e spostare grafico in \
Mathematica\\PlotExplorer.m"]

Comment: Well, it still looks like you are using one "\" there. Ok, try with "/" instead. Windows also works with forward slash but you do not need to worry about escaping it. You seem to have problem with the path. Why not try to put the file in same directory your nbotebook is in first to test?  Make sure to set the notebook directoy as in `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]` at top and now just do `Get["plotExplorer.m"]`

Comment: @Nasser thank you a lot for the last solution. It works. Instead these two gave errors: (1) Get["C:\\Users\\Gennaro\\Desktop\\Funzione PlotExplorer (non \
integrata) per ingrandire (zoomare,fare zoom) e spostare grafico in \
Mathematica\\PlotExplorer.m"] (2) Get["C:/Users/Gennaro/Desktop/Funzione PlotExplorer (non integrata) \
per ingrandire (zoomare,fare zoom) e spostare grafico in \
Mathematica/PlotExplorer.m"]